# Read Data from .ics URL with WSO2 EI

Tags: wso2, wso2-integration-studio

I am currently making my first steps with the `WSO2 Integration Studio 8.1.0`. Is it possible to query an `.ics` calendar link to process the appointments? And which mediator should I use here?

I have searched for information in the `WSO2` documentation and unfortunately have not found anything on this topic.

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ATM, WSO2 doesn't have any connectors to process `.ics` files. You may need to write a custom class mediator to carry out the required functions. Please refer to the following for more information,

- iCal4j is a Java library used to read and write iCalendar data streams
  https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mnode.ical4j/ical4j
- java sample code to read a `ics` file
  https://www.tutorialsbuddy.com/create-ics-calendar-file-in-java
- Writing a Custom Class Mediator
  https://medium.com/think-integration/esb-few-tips-in-writing-a-custom-class-mediator-b9a322f4eaa8
- https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/integrate/develop/customizations/creating-custom-mediators/